# Why does this simple JSFiddle not work?

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

There is some code I wanted to put into JSFiddle. It didn’t work. Narrowing it down I can’t even get this simplest of code to work:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomasf1/XNJxT/5/)

```js
function displaymessage() {
  alert("Hello World!");
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="displaymessage()" />
</form>

<p>By pressing the button above, a function will be called. The function will alert a message.</p>
```

The `alert` box doesn’t show up in the JSFiddle.

Comment: "Didn't work" is not a problem description.

Comment: @thomasf1: Please change your accepted answer to the earlier and completer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7043684/295783

Answer (score -6, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_prasad/XNJxT/14/

Js fiddle  so something like this to whatever you write

```
window.addEvent('load',function(){

//Your code


});
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Is this an explanation ? A solution ?

Answer (score 36):

Select `No wrap - bottom of <head>` in the “Load type” dropdown in the JavaScript settings.

[image: Screenshot of the dropdown mentioned above]

Comment: Thanks! I was sure I was missing something. Stupid me!

Comment: Ok, now it works. But what exactly means *no wrap (head)*? What is it doing or not doing?

Comment: @BlakeWebb rerun the "project" so that the change takes effect.

Comment: And as of Jan 2018

Comment: It appears that this option is now gone.

Answer (score 9):

You need to take your [function out of the onLoad/onReady](http://jsfiddle.net/XNJxT/12/) otherwise it is placed inside of another scope and your button cannot access the function.  In your case you need to use
    No wrap (head)

The code generated looks like this:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    function displaymessage()
    {
        alert("Hello World!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the code to run "no wrap (head)" instead of "onDomReady". Your function isn't visible to your markup as is.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some of you need to move your function outside of **document.ready** if you use html onclick="func()"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ...
}

function func(){
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still have problems, check whether you have

1. AdBlockers installed as a browser extension? (i.e. AdBlocker Plus)

[image]

2. Turn off AdBlockers in JSFiddle and run again.

I hope this helps some one.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry but... is much simpler than what you propose...

If you want to call a js function with "onclick" attribute, put your javascrit code directly in head, you dont need domready or similars.

Second, you need to include "javascript:" before the function name.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/XNJxT/1838/

```
<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="javascript:displaymessage()" />
```

Comment: As stated [in this beautiful answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11348403/1908115) the `javascript:` is not recommended (bad practice).

Answer (score -4):

My problem to this was when I made my script tag I typed it out :

```
script type="javascript/text"
```

instead of :

```
script type="text/javascript"
```

and now it works.