# Run JavaScript Function onkeyup not working

Tags: javascript

I got old code of my apps that using javascript to calculate something, the logic is if 1 textbox filled, another textbox automatic filled, and when the second textbox filled, that another textbox will return text1 - text2, maybe You can look at this fiddle:

HTML:

```
<label>Price Start</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Total Harga Diberikan" required="required" name="price" onkeyup="calculate()" id="price" />
<br />
<label>Discount</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Nominal Potongan" name="jmlvoucher" onkeyup="calculate()" id="jmlvoucher" />
<br />
<label>Total</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Total yang harus dibayarkan" required="required" name="total" id="total" />
```

Javascript:

```
function calculate(){
    var num1 = document.getElementById("price").value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("jmlvoucher").value;

    var sum=parseFloat(num1)-parseFloat(num2);
    document.getElementById('total').value=sum.toString();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n4anv5qn/2/

Already try to check error, but there's no error. Try to run it, it doesn't works. Any idea why?

Comment: You did not link to the fiddle

Comment: sorry... there's error from stackoverflow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this simple JSFiddle not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043649/why-does-this-simple-jsfiddle-not-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There indeed is an error being generated as keyup is fired.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: calculate is not defined
```

On JSFiddle you've chosen to put your JavaScript into the `onLoad` function which is wrong. You should instead choose `No Wrap`

See http://jsfiddle.net/n4anv5qn/5/

As requested, this code is an example of how you can still calculate your Total if your Discount is not filled. Simply check to see if the value you grabbed from num2 is blank and set it to a default value.

```
function calculate(){
    var num1 = document.getElementById("price").value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("jmlvoucher").value;

    if (num2 == '')
        num2 = '0';

    var sum=parseFloat(num1)-parseFloat(num2);
    document.getElementById('total').value=sum.toString();
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Another option is to define a global function if he uses `onLoad` event: `var target = document || window; target.calculate = function() { /* ... */ };`

Comment: sorry, there's misunderstanding, if I type only in textbox 1, the third textbox must be filled too... Then if I type in textbox 2, the third textbox will substract text1 with text2... also, how to write nowrap at my php code?

Comment: `No Wrap` in the context of JSFiddle simply means do not put your provided Javascript inside another piece of Javascript code. You can see Psioniax's example of where to put your Javascript. I've also added your request to the answer.

Comment: well, after putting the code to bottom my code works well.... thank you... I confused where to put answered marks.. on you or on Psioniax?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `onchange` instead of `onkeyup`. Also put your scripts right before the closing body tag.

Here's how to do it:

```html
<label>Price Start</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control"name="price" onchange="calculate()" id="price" />
    <br />
    <label>Discount</label>
     <input type="number" class="form-control" onchange="calculate()" id="jmlvoucher" />
    <br />
    <label>Total</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" required="required" name="total" id="total" />

    <script>
    function calculate(){
  var num1 = document.getElementById("price").value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById("jmlvoucher").value;

  var sum = parseFloat(num1) - parseFloat(num2);
  document.getElementById('total').value = sum;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Yeah, but I changed it before moving the script at the bottom. And IMO `onchange` is better anyway.

Comment: @I'mnidhin. `onkeyup` is a keyboard event, it will fail if the user enters input using the arrow keys beside the input(using mouse).

Comment: @Psioniax, in your example, event is being triggerer after the input element goes i blur state wheras if you go with keyup event, calculation will take place after the keyboard event is fired..

Comment: What if I use the mouse to click on the arrows? Then there will be no event fired (related to the keyboard).

Comment: doesn't work... @Ryan solution is what I want but there's a little misunderstood...