# How can I ensure that my function is being called and running

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am creating a form validation here. I want to ask how does form validation works. The script i have here does not seem to return anything as the error given on the JS console is that the `ValidateForm()` function is undefined.

HTML:

```
    <form name="myForm" action="ControllerServlet" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  <tr>
    <td class="newusertd">Name:<span class="price">*</span></td>
    <td class="newusertd">
      <input style="color: black;" type="text" name="name" class="Btn">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="newusertd">Contact Number:<span class="price">*</span></td>
    <td class="newusertd">
      <input style="color: black;" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="98989898" class="Btn">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="newusertd">Email:<span class="price">*<br></span></td>
    <td class="newusertd">
      <input style="color: black;" type="text" name="email" placeholder="xxx@hello.com" class="Btn">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="newusertd">Address:<span class="price">*</span></td>
    <td class="newusertd">
      <input style="color: black;" type="text" name="address" class="Btn">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="newusertd">Password:<span class="price">*</span>
      <br>(8-16 Characters with
      <br>one UPPERCASE & numbers)</td>
    <td class="newusertd">
      <input style="color: black;" type="password" name="password" class="Btn">
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="newusertd"></td>
    <td class="newusertd">
      <input style="color: black;" type="submit" value="Create Account" class="Btn" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

JS:

```
 function validateForm() {
  var name = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
  var phone = document.forms["myForm"]["phone"].value;
  var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
  var add = document.forms["myForm"]["address"].value;
  var passwd = document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;
  var matchesCount = email.split("@").length - 1;
  var matchesCount2 = email.split(".").length - 1;
  var error = "";
  if (!name || !phone || !email || !add || !passwd) {
    error += "All must be filled out \n"

    if (phone.search(/^[0-9]*$/) == -1 || phone.length != 8) {
      error += "- Phone number can only contain digits \n";
    }

    if (passwd.search(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/) == -1) {
      error += "- Password needs to be alphanumeric \n";
    }

    if (passwd.length < 8 || passwd.length > 16) {
      error += "- Password contain only 8-16 digits \n";
    }

    if (matchesCount > 1 || matchesCount2 < 1) {
      error += "- Please enter a valid email \n";
    }
    alert(error);
    return false;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/KodeError404/wpwv614c/

Please inform me if you cannot see the JSFiddle.

In the script I am checking if all fields are filled and if its not filled, it should return `false`. I would appreciate if this is kept strictly to JS and not JQuery.

**EDIT: This issue is that the password does not seem to check if i key in anything or if its alphanumeric with Uppercase. I want to know why does all fields get checked but not my password field**

Comment: JSFiddle defaults to putting any code you enter for javascript into an onload event. Try changing the settings to put in the `<head>`

Comment: I thnink you should not check against null because value will be at least an empty sting ""... so .trim your value and check against == ""

Comment: @PatrickEvans May I know where? I just started using JSFiddle so I am not sure even after clicking on the Settings tab on the right

Comment: Click the "Javascript" label in the javascript window you will get a drop down, change "Load Type"

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043649/why-does-this-simple-jsfiddle-not-work, however this doesn’t seem to be the only thing wrong with the fiddle…

Comment: @PatrickEvans Hi, could you check out this and tell me where did i go wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/KodeError404/0w4po318/

Comment: @RuslanBes Hi, I have figured that but now i would like to clarify the mistakes i have in my script. do see my fiddle jsfiddle.net/KodeError404/0w4po318

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised i could break up the regex for the password to check the conditions individually.

```js
function validateForm() {
  var name = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
  var phone = document.forms["myForm"]["phone"].value;
  var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
  var add = document.forms["myForm"]["address"].value;
  var passwd = document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;
  var matchesCount = email.split("@").length - 1;
  var matchesCount2 = email.split(".").length - 1;
  var error = "";
  if (name == '' || phone == '' || email == '' || add == '' || passwd == '') {
    error += "All must be filled out \n"
  } else {
    if (phone.search(/^[0-9]*$/) == -1 || phone.length != 8) {
      error += "- Phone number can only contain digits \n";
    }
    if (passwd.search(/[A-Z]/) == -1) {
      error += "- Password needs to be have one UPPERCASE\n";
    }

    if (passwd.search(/[a-z]/) == -1) {
      error += "- Password needs to be have letters\n";
    }

    if (passwd.search(/[0-9]/) == -1) {
      error += "- Password needs to be have numbers\n";
    }

    if (passwd.length < 8 || passwd.length > 16) {
      error += "- Password contain only 8-16 digits \n";
    }

    if (matchesCount > 1 || matchesCount2 < 1) {
      error += "- Please enter a valid email \n";
    }
  }
  alert(error);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" action="ControllerServlet" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  <table>

    <tr>
      <td class="newusertd">Name:<span class="price">*</span>
      </td>
      <td class="newusertd">
        <input style="color: black;" type="text" name="name" class="Btn">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="newusertd">Contact Number:<span class="price">*</span>
      </td>
      <td class="newusertd">
        <input style="color: black;" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="98989898" class="Btn">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="newusertd">Email:<span class="price">*<br></span>
      </td>
      <td class="newusertd">
        <input style="color: black;" type="text" name="email" placeholder="xxx@hello.com" class="Btn">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="newusertd">Address:<span class="price">*</span>
      </td>
      <td class="newusertd">
        <input style="color: black;" type="text" name="address" class="Btn">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="newusertd">Password:<span class="price">*</span>
        <br>(8-16 Characters with
        <br>one UPPERCASE & numbers)</td>
      <td class="newusertd">
        <input style="color: black;" type="password" name="password" class="Btn">
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="newusertd"></td>
      <td class="newusertd">
        <input style="color: black;" type="submit" value="Create Account" class="Btn" />
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</form>
```