# Getting function not defined on keyup of input element

Tags: javascript

Given the following table (a slightly modified version of this one at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_table)) but searches all columns, I'm getting the error that `searchAttorneys is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup` when entering a value in the textbox. Also, how can I keep the table headers from disappearing when searching the table?

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="search-attorneys" onkeyup="searchAttorneys()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
```

JS

```
function searchAttorneys() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("search-attorneys");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("attorneys");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    var found = false;
    for (j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
      td = tds[j];
      if (td) {
        if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (found) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

**JSFIDDLE: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/1zg85s9s/1/)**

Comment: It is not defined above the element on the w3schools site.

Comment: @Matt if you have no document ready listener it needs to be assigned before call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this simple JSFiddle not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043649/why-does-this-simple-jsfiddle-not-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="search-attorneys" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('search-atorneys').on('keyup', function(){
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("search-attorneys");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("attorneys");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
      var found = false;
      for (j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
        td = tds[j];
        if (td) {
          if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            found = true;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      if (found) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  });
});
```

execute from inside js and not from inside html is mostly the better way.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle, but the search isn't firing still: https://jsfiddle.net/1zg85s9s/4/

Comment: A little `#` would be welcome at: `$('search-atorneys').on(...` make it like: ``$('#search-atorneys').on(...`` as `search-atorneys` is `id`

Answer (score 0):

Set your jsfiddle javascript load type to nowrap (either one). The other 2 (onload/ondomready) will wrap the function inside another function, making it invisible to your inline onkeyup.

Comment: Got that fixed, but how do I keep the table headers from disappearing when typing: https://jsfiddle.net/1zg85s9s/2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1zg85s9s/5/ search in tbody and not in the complete table. so the thead is not touched by the search