# function is not defined at htmlinputelement.onfocus

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to call function when onfocus event occur in input field but its gives error that

> function is not defined at htmlinputelement.onfocus
>   
>   HTML:

`<input type="text" class="form-control" onFocus="forFocus(this);"  id="name" 
  aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Name">`

Javscript function:

`function forFocus(element){
   console.log('here on focus is called now', element);
 }`
[image: image of error which occure]

Please help link http://jsfiddle.net/7gxnr7cb/18/

Comment: can't replicate with the given info. it just works.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. You've failed on the "Complete" and "Verifiable" parts of that.

Comment: @Quentin http://jsfiddle.net/7gxnr7cb/11/

Comment: @Redu http://jsfiddle.net/7gxnr7cb/18/ check this

Comment: @aashir khan it doesn't work since you give the callback name inline and while html is parsed the function is undefined. So you best chose how JS is loaded from JS window top right menu of jsfiddle. Make sure that No Wrap -  in <head> or No Wrap - in <body> is selected..

Comment: @aashirkhan — You're supposed to put the [mcve] **in the question**. Don't host it elsewhere and just link to it.

Comment: Also: Duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043649/why-does-this-simple-jsfiddle-not-work

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
function func1() {
    console.log('func1');    
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="foo" onfocus="func1()">
```

see [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Faizi24/x8pgd75n/)