# onclick called method is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code running on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n3cosgvr/3/).  The code is below.  I can bet a ton of money this is me doing something stupid, but I can't find it.

Clicking on  says that *Uncaught ReferenceError: showDetail is not defined*

I have tried varying adding of parameters as well just to try and troubleshoot.  Passing none, one, two doesn't effect the error message.

```
const lcAppdata = {

    matters: [{
        mid: 100,
        title: "Matter1",
        dateOpened: "01/01/17",
        decedent: "Elvis Presley",
        personalRepresentative: "Alexis Texas",
        attorneyAccountInfo: "John Holmes"
    }, {
        mid: 200,
        title: "Matter2",
        dateOpened: "01/02/16",
        decedent: "Kurt Cobain",
        personalRepresentative: "Kagney Linn Karter",
        attorneyAccountInfo: "Simon Rex"
    }, {
        mid: 300,
        title: "Matter3",
        dateOpened: "01/03/15",
        decedent: "Bob Marley",
        personalRepresentative: "Nikki Benz",
        attorneyAccountInfo: "Ron Jeremy"
    }],
    currentMatter: ''
};


function showDetail(mid){
    console.log(mid);
};

function init(){
    for(let matter of lcAppdata.matters){
    $('#tbodyMatterList').append(`<tr 
            onclick="showDetail(${matter.mid})"> 
            <th scope="row" >${matter.title}</th>
            <td bind>${matter.decedent}</td>
            <td bind>${matter.dateOpened}</td>
            <td bind>${matter.personalRepresentative}</td>
            <td bind>${matter.attorneyAccountInfo}</td></tr>`);

    }


};

init();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this simple JSFiddle not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043649/why-does-this-simple-jsfiddle-not-work) — look at the highest voted answer, past the accepted one.

Comment: what is not working

Comment: @Xufox thanks for the suggestion, that is not it.

Comment: @Sajeetharan clicking on the row is saying the method is not defined, but i have it defined

Comment: @RobinMasters If it’s not a duplicate, you need to explain _how exactly_ it is not one. So far, we can’t verify this and the link I provided should definitely fix the error.

Comment: You fiddle works when the `LOAD TYPE ` of the Javascript in the fiddle is set to `No wrap - in <body>`

Comment: I see, you also need to wrap the `init` IIFE in `$(document).ready(function(){`…`});`.

Comment: The real solution would be to not append strings with inline JS, but create proper elements with proper event handlers

Comment: @adeneo can you share a link that explains further what you're saying here?

Comment: I'll be your Magnum here, and show you how you'd create element -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/a3v9es4q/ ... how that works with your templates inside JS *(which you should probably also avoid)* I don't know ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code is fine, it's because of how jsfiddle runs your script. It's set to run the script `onLoad` i.e. all your code is actually run inside the callback of `load` event so your function `showDetail` is not actually defined as a global function, but only local to the load event callback

You can either change your code to attach the `showDetail` function to the `window` object to make it global like this

```
function showDetail() {
  console.log($(this).attr('data-mid'));
};

window.showDetail = showDetail;
```

or change jsfiddle settings to run your script globally like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way

```
function showDetail() {
  console.log($(this).attr('data-mid'));
};


(function init() {
    for (let matter of lcAppdata.matters) {
        $('#tbodyMatterList').append(`<tr data-mid=${matter.mid}><th scope="row" >${matter.title}</th>
        <td bind>${matter.decedent}</td>
        <td bind>${matter.dateOpened}</td>
        <td bind>${matter.personalRepresentative}</td>
        <td bind>${matter.attorneyAccountInfo}</td></tr>`);
    }

    $('#tbodyMatterList tr').click(showDetail);
})();
```

In JSFiddle you have to init methods in a different way the way you want to achieve it