# Javascript error: function is not defined at HTMLTableCellElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, tic-tac-toe

So I'm trying to make a tic-tac-toe game on HTML/JS, however my onclicks just kind of stopped working, the error I get now is that all the functions are not defined. I tried changing my clear() function to jQuery but I am unable to test it.

[Here is a jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/61bjf77s/3/)

Essentially, It's getting this html

```
 <td class="tile" id="pos1" onclick="draw(this); checkWinner();"></td>
```

To recognize this javascript function

```
var counter = 0;
function draw(elmt){
    if(elmt.innerHTML == "x" || elmt.innerHTML == "o")
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    else{
    if(counter==0){
        elmt.innerHTML = "x";
        counter = 1;
    }
    else{
        elmt.innerHTML = "o";
        counter = 0;
    }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: [Why does this simple JSFiddle not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043649/why-does-this-simple-jsfiddle-not-work) – JSFiddle defaults to running the JavaScript you provide after an event. This is often useful, but changes the scope of the functions so `on*` attributes can't reach them. You'll need to either change the setting or how you're binding the events.

Answer (score 0):

Your `checkWinner` function is not defined， and make sure all your functions is defined to the global scope, for example, you must can access to the `window.draw()`.

At last, you can also use jQuery to bind event handler conveniently, like:

```

```
$('.tile').on('click', draw);

function draw(e) {
  var html = $(this).html();
  if(html == "x" || html == "o")
  {
    //do nothing
  } else{
    if(counter==0){
      $(this).html("x");
      counter = 1;
    }
    else{
      $(this).html("o");
      counter = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```

```js
var counter = 0;
function draw(elmt){
    if(elmt.innerHTML == "x" || elmt.innerHTML == "o")
    {
        //do nothing
    } else{
      if(counter==0){
          elmt.innerHTML = "x";
          counter = 1;
      }
      else{
          elmt.innerHTML = "o";
          counter = 0;
      }
    }
}
function checkWinner(){

}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class="tile" id="pos1" onclick="draw(this); checkWinner();">
Click Here
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess their must be something wrong with jsfiddle you can try this your code is working for me

```
[just remove `$( document ).ready(function() {})`]
```