# JavaScript, HTML, CSS - How to Restrict Number / Value Allowed in Input Field With - Validity Check

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/gcqojLfp/2/

**1.)** The js fiddle isn't rendering the `<div>` with the id `result2` from the HTML.

After clicking the button, the `multiply()` function should run and it should get the `innerHTML` of the `<div>` with id `result2`.

I'm not sure why nothing is happening after clicking on the button in the fiddle. It should say:

> "All of the numbers between 1 and 5 multiplied together equals: 120"

(if 5 is entered, for example). We should see this displayed in the `result2` div.

**2.)** Why is the text field with id `factorialInput` not restricting the input to 10 at the max? I thought that I had set the max for this input field here:

`<input id="factorialInput" type="number" max="10" size="20"/>`

(as per answers from [other articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-can-i-limit-possible-inputs-in-a-html5-number-element)).

I've tried `maxlength` as well - I don't understand why it's allowing numbers 11 and up.

Any ideas?

**JavaScript**

```
function multiply() {
    let num = document.getElementById("factorialInput").value;
    let sum = 1;
    for (let i=1; i<= num; i++) {
        sum = sum * i;
    }

    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML  = "All of the numbers between 
    1 and " + num + " multiplied together equals: " + sum ;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <form id="enterValue">
    Enter a number between 1 and 10: 
    <input id="factorialInput" type="number" max="10" size="20"/>
    <input type ="button" value="Submit" onclick="multiply();" max="10" />
    </form>
    <br><br>
<div id="result2"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row {
    height: 200px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043649/why-does-this-simple-jsfiddle-not-work

Comment: What exactly do you expect from restricting the range? If a number larger than 10 is entered, the input is properly marked as invalid, but your code doesn't check for that.

Comment: @Bergi yes I still need to finish writing the code to check for invalid entries - I'm just trying to restrict entries to 1 - 10 via HTML and JS first if that's possible

Comment: What do you expect to happen when an invalid value is entered?

Comment: @Bergi I'll need to write some code for it, but I'll need for the for loop to not execute and instead display a message in the `result2` div - "please enter a number between 1 and 10". I guess I'll need an `if-else` statement. But what @Hien Nguyen answered with below was what I was looking for initially.

Comment: I think @Shilly's code with [`reportValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) is strictly better suited for that

Comment: so `reportValidity` will check if the input is valid based on `min` and `max`?

Comment: Yes, and as a bonus it will even show a proper localised error message.

Comment: Okay, I will accept @Shilly's answer in that case. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check manually if the input is valid or not, as described in the docs.

```js
function multiply() {
  let input = document.getElementById("factorialInput");
  if ( input.reportValidity() ) {
    let num = input.value;
    let sum = 1;
    for (let i=1; i<= num; i++) {
      sum = sum * i;
    }
    let message = "All of the numbers between 1 and " + num + " multiplied together equals: " + sum;
    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML  = message;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <form id="enterValue">
      Enter a number between 1 and 10: 
      <input id="factorialInput" type="number" max="10" size="20"/>
      <input type ="button" value="Submit" onclick="multiply();" max="10" />
    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
  <div id="result2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**First** if you look at the console, there is an error that the multiply function is not defined.
Moving the javascript inline above the html resolves the missing function reference.

**Second** The `input` type number restricts number inputs to the max value set if you use the increment/decrement arrows, but it does not stop the user from entering a larger number. If you need to stop input of larger numbers, you can achieve this by using an `onkeyup` or `onkeydown` event to change the input value.

Updated fiddle with changes mentioned applied:
https://jsfiddle.net/6pagfr2t/

Comment: Sorry but to start with I do not see a console in jsfiddle:

https://i.imgur.com/21JB5UK.png - but yes moving the JS inline into the HTML certainly resolves the missing function reference: https://jsfiddle.net/gcqojLfp/4/

Comment: Jako is talking about the browser console, which is most accessible in Chrome and Firefox. I noticed that the fiddle itself has the JavaScript being added/executed on document load. Changing it to be included in the header made it work for me.

Comment: @HappyHands31yes as stated by J.T. I'm referring to the browser console which can be opened using F12 in most modern browsers. Javascript errors not handled by code is shows in your browser console which is useful for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement event keyup keydown to prevent invalid value.

```
$('#factorialInput').on('keydown keyup', function(e){
    if ($(this).val() > 10 
        && e.keyCode !== 46 // keycode for delete
        && e.keyCode !== 8 // keycode for backspace
       ) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/mrt6hw8c/6/

Comment: Awesome because this way I don't even have to rewrite the function to check to see if the number entered is greater than 10. Thank you.

Comment: There are other ways to input a value than with the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can do a validity pattern check WITHOUT Javascript. The HTML 5 input spec allows the use of a `regex` to make an input valid/invalid.

**Important note: This only returns a TRUE/FALSE.** It's up to you to handle to create and display any errors.

Examples:

```
<input type="number" pattern="[1-9]|0[1-9]|10" placeholder="1 to 10" value="" />
```

And CSS

```
input:valid {
  background-color: green;
}

input:invalid {
  background-color: red;
}
```

More info about [styling valid/invalid inputs](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/v/valid/)