# Simple Javascript code (function) is not working

Tags: javascript, html

The simple javascript is not working. When I test the code in live preview (chrome), it says "ThfJ8q9:58 Uncaught ReferenceError: textpage is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (ThfJ8q9:58)"

What I am trying to do is to change the background image of the div "chat" when the button is clicked to the new image specified.

HTML:

```
<div id="chat"> 
    <div class="button-class">
     <button type="button" onclick="textpage()"> <img class= "submit-button- 
      img" alt="submit-button" src="images/text.button.png"> </button>
    </div>  
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT DOCUMENT:

```
function textpage() {
document.getElementById("chat").style.backgroundImage = "url('full-convesation- 
MRP.png')";
}
```

Comment: Sounds like `textpage` isn't global

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that shows the actual problem.

Comment: Might be because a closing bracket is missing somewhere in your code. You will need to provide us more then that.

Comment: with this.textpage does it work ?

Comment: Is your javascript code in the HTML file itself or separate js file?

Comment: @cocool97 why would this.textpage work?

Comment: Where are you executing this code? In JSFiddle? See [Why does this simple JSFiddle not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7043649/4642212).

Comment: @sanketd617 and why not ?

Comment: @cocool97 Inside the `onclick`, `this` refers to the `<button>` element. Why would this element have the `textpage` function on its prototype chain?

Comment: @cocool97 Because if you call `this.textpage` in onclick of a button, `this` will refer to the button itself and button doesn't have a method named `textpage`.

Comment: @sanketd617 no its not should it be?

Comment: @cocool97 should my onclick reference be somewhere else in that line?

Comment: @Sophie no it's not mandatory.

Comment: @SophieSheppard It all depends on _where_ the JS is, in relation to the HTML. Please [edit] your question and show a _minimal, but complete_ HTML document.

Comment: @SophieSheppard I highly recommend you create a jsfiddle.net that reproduces your problem. It will allow us to see exactly what you are doing wrong (and it is quite likely you will discover the cause of your issues in the process)

Comment: @Omn JSFiddle isn’t the right choice here, because it may create exactly the same issue and it wouldn’t reveal where the problem is. Again, see [Why does this simple JSFiddle not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7043649/4642212).

Comment: @sanketd617 Just solved the issue by adding the code into the html file. I believe there may have been a order issue as I have other JS files linked in my html. Thank you for your help!

Comment: How do I say solved on an issue? Haha i'm new to this website!

Comment: @Sophie how about adding the answer yourself and marking it as accepted? ;)

Comment: Your image path is wrong may be.. check once

Answer (score 0):

Could use something like this to listen for a click on the button

https://codepen.io/CTBroon/pen/RwbRGQq

**HTML**

```
    <div id="chat"> 
        <div class="button-class">
         <button type="button" id="btns"> <img class= "submit-button- 
          img" alt="submit-button" src="images/text.button.png"> </button>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
    var btntrigger = document.getElementById('btns');

    btntrigger.addEventListener('click', function(){
      document.getElementById("chat").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://placehold.it/400x400')";
    })
```

Or have a closer look at your syntax on the orginal, fixed here:

https://codepen.io/CTBroon/pen/RwbRGQq

**HTML**

```
    <div id="chat"> 
        <div class="button-class">
         <button type="button" onclick="textpage()">
           <img class="submit-button-img" alt="submit-button" src="images/text.button.png"> </button>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
function textpage() {
  document.getElementById("chat").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://placehold.it/400x400')";
}
```

:)