# making the link variable when loading an iFrame with JS

Tags: javascript, variables, getelementbyid

I want to load an HTML page into an iFrame with JS instead of using the usual iFrame target. Long story. That's just how I need it to be. My Javscript is

```
onclick = function buttonLife() {
    var el=document.getElementById("divContent");
    el.innerHTML="<iframe width=1024 height=702 scrolling=no name=bottomFrame frameborder=0 src=page.html></iframe>";
}
```

And my HTML is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="buttonLife();">BUTTON</a>;
```

And it works. But it loads a page already defined by the above java function. However, if I want to make the page I load into the iFrame variable for each button with the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="buttonLife('page2.html');">BUTTON2</a>
```

I know I need to change the have function to something like

```
onclick = function buttonLife() {
    var el=document.getElementById("divContent");
    el.innerHTML="<iframe width=1024 height=702 scrolling=no name=bottomFrame frameborder=0 src='link'></iframe>";
}
```

But it doesn't work. Help! Thanks

Comment: I suggest trying to explain this question; it's been a while since it was asked, and while I've looked, I still don't know what it is that you want help with. Clicking the `a` element works, or doesn't work? If it doesn't work, what effect should it have; and how is it going wrong? It's worth looking at this article "[Writing the Perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)," by [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), for pointers.

Comment: Not sure what part is not clear. Yes, as I said, it works. If what I want is to load a page determined by the Java function. That works.

Then the very next sentence is "But it loads a page already defined by the above java function. However, if I want to make the page I load into the iFrame variable for each button..."

Answer (score 2):

1. The function as you've created it doesn't accept any parameter; you're trying to pass it `'page2.html'`, but it doesn't expect this input.
2. You're also expecting the `link` variable to be automatically interpolated, but Javascript does not interpolate variables in strings. The solution instead is to concatenate the variable with the strings.
3. `onclick = function buttonLife()` probably does not do what you intend it to do; what it does is define a function, called `buttonLife`, and store it to a variable, called `onclick`. Instead you just want to create the function `buttonLife()`.

Here's the function corrected to resolve the above issues:

```
function buttonLife( page ) {
    var el=document.getElementById("divContent");
    el.innerHTML="<iframe width=1024 height=702 scrolling=no name=bottomFrame frameborder=0 src='" + page + "'></iframe>";
}


<a href="#" onclick="buttonLife('page2.html');">BUTTON2</a>
```

[MDN's guide to Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) is a good basic introduction and will help you avoid these sorts of problems.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That did it too.

Answer (score 0):

So I took your code and tried it out in jsfiddle and it works fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZK2VB/

I made the following changes:

- Removed the pointless `onclick =`
- Made it so you can pass the URL to the function in variable `pageUrl`
- Removed `href="#"` to so when you click the links it doesn't move the page
- I added the `<div id="contentDiv">`

But these are only cosmetic / to create the real-world implementation.

If you use the code as I am this should work, unless you have some other problem, like you redefined the function somewhere, or you're trying to call the function before it's defined.

Comment: Yes, there were a bunch of errors. Thanks for clarifying. Now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function buttonLife(page_url)
{
  var el = document.getElementById("divContent");
  el.innerHTML = "<iframe width=1024 height=702 scrolling=no name=bottomFrame frameborder=0 src=" + page_url + "></iframe>";
}
```

Also, I recommend you to use:

```
<a href="javascript:buttonLife('page1.html')">BUTTON</a>;
```

Comment: Use of `href="javascript:/* some js */"` is generally not recommended (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-function-in-href-vs-onclick). Choose JavaScript events instead. Also, the `javascript:` method can have other (probably undesired) consequences in IEs: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t303342-href-javascript-func-vs-href-onclick-javascript-func.html#postmenu_1606021.

Comment: @Robin Winslow, Thanks for links. But anyway, I think href="javascript()" is good because users need to know that this link do (or where go).