# Href attribute using variable does not work

Tags: javascript, variables, href, alert

In JS, I am creating a link where the href attribute runs a function. The function simple opens an alert window with a given variable.

```
function alerter(str){
    alert(str);
}
```

When I create the link, I use the following code.

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href','javascript:alerter("hi")');
link.innerHTML = "Sauce";
```

If I do that, it works. However, what I want to do is alert a previously defined variable. But when i use

```
link.setAttribute('href','javascript:alerter(myvar)');
```

the popup no longer works. Also, is there a way to simply embed the alert in the href instead of writing a separate function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
link.setAttribute('href','javascript:alerter("' + myvar + '")');
```

You're using string concatenation to put `myvar` into that string. The way you had it, the whole thing is a string "javascript:alerter(myvar)"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
link.setAttribute('href','javascript:alerter('+myvar+')');
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/xmBbw/2/

Just modify the onclick event of your anchor. If you are not going to link anywhere, you need not use the href attribute. Rather use onclick and assign any function you like to it. Besides, it's awfully bad practice to write javascript inside an html tag. Please [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-function-in-href-vs-onclick?rq=1).

[A nice article regarding good practices](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/)

Answer (score 0):

The `myvar` variable has to be in the global scope. Be sure you can also access it as `window.myvar`.

Answer (score 0):

for your first question use :

```
link.setAttribute('href','javascript:alerter(' + somevar + ')');
```

and for your second question use:

```
link.setAttribute('href','javascript:alert(' + somevar + ')');
```

cheers.