# Window.location.href not working in Google Chrome

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to pass an id for an item to be deleted through the URL after OK is clicked in a confirmation box, however nothing happens. This does works in IE but I'd like it to work with Chrome as well.

```
<script>
function dltCnfrm(id)
{
    var r=confirm("Delete this product?")
    if (r)
    {
        window.location.href = "http://localhost/e-com/index.php/product/delete_item/" + id;
    }
}
</script>
```

code inside html

```
foreach ($items as $res) {
$id = $res['id'];
.
.
<td><?php echo "<a href='' onclick='dltCnfrm($id)'>Delete</a>"; ?></td>
```

I have also tried several other methods including

```
location.assign();
```

adding return false; underneath the if statement

could someone try this using a Chrome browser?
Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57 m

Comment: something else is happening

Comment: Agreed with @Shanimal - something else is going on. Check your JS console for errors.

Comment: Try: `<a href='' onclick='dltCnfrm($id);return false;'>Delete</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am betting the id is a string so you have an error

```
<td><?php echo "<a href='' onclick='dltCnfrm(\"$id\")'>Delete</a>"; ?></td>
```

You probably want to cancel the link click also.

```
<td><?php echo "<a href='' onclick='dltCnfrm(\"$id\"); return false'>Delete</a>"; ?></td>
```

**BUT you should never never never do a delete action with a GET request.** GET is for fetching data, POST is for updating data.

Comment: Thanks, the solution works, but could you explain to me what you mean by "cancel the link click", by the way I'm using post not get.

Comment: By looking at the example, he means to stop the default `onclick` behavior (following the link) and execute the JS function only. See more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-function-in-href-vs-onclick#answer-11348403

Comment: Where is the POST? Setting window.location is a GET request. There is no form posting going on.