# href="javascript:func()" vs href="#" onclick="javascript:func()"

Tags: javascript, html

```
<a href="javascript:expand()">  and <a href="#" onclick="javascript:expand()">
```

What's the difference?

I know the `href="#"` is the more standard way nowadays to do it. My problem is I have a standard dropdown menu that expands/collapses when user clicks on toggle.

If I do `href="#"` for the code below, whenever someone clicks on expand the page ALWAYS scroll right back to the top which isn't acceptable from a user friendly point.

If I use `href="javascript:expand()"` when user clicks expand, the page doesn't move and everything is OK.

So will there be any problems if I just use `href="javascript:expand()"` instead?  or how do I fix the `href="#"` so the page doesn't scroll back to the top whenever user clicks expand.

Thanks.

EDIT: I know this question may have been asked before, but i'm looking at it from my point of view. Im just asking for a suggestion rather than an explanation.

Comment: Maybe put onclick="return false;" with the href="javascript:expand()"

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript function in href vs. onclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-function-in-href-vs-onclick)

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0

Comment: Note that you do _not_ need the `javascript:` part in the event attribute. Just say `onclick="expand();"` (or `onclick="expand();return false;"` if you want to prevent the page from scrolling/navigating due to the default `href="#"`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your JavaScript `onclick` event handler returns `false`, the scrolling won't occur. You can do it like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="expand(); return false;">
```

If your onclick handler does not return `false`, the `href` link will be followed. In the case of `href="#"`, that means scroll to the top of the page.

Comment: This is wrong. For that to happen, the inline event handler would have to return the return value of `expand()`, which it doesn't

Comment: `javascript:` inside `onclick`?

Answer (score 3):

The best choice is to not use `<a>` element. Use any semantically appropriate element or just `<div>` instead.

Comment: An anchor is better than a div because an anchor is accessible via the keyboard for users who can't use (or who choose not to use) a mouse or other pointing device.

Comment: Is `<a>` semantically inappropriate? It contradicts with my knowledge. (No offence, real question.)

Comment: I think `<a>` should be used for real links (for parsers, RSS readers or anything else that don't understand javascript). If you care about keyboard-only users, you could try `<button>`, but you will need to put more CSS on it.

Comment: AFAIK, any element can become accessible from keyboard if it has the proper `tabindex`. Also, good practice is labeling such elements with ARIA `role="button"`. Using `a` elements with fake `href` may be the easiest way, but I doubt that it's the right way because it breaks the user's expectations of the link behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the `href="#"` you could do

```
function expand(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  // ...
}
```

which prevents the default anchor click behaviour to take place, or you could return false at the end of it.

For the rest, have a look at this question: [JavaScript function in href vs. onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-function-in-href-vs-onclick), which I believe is basically what you're asking.

Comment: This wouldn't work unless the inline `onclick` was updated to actually pass the event object into the function. (And still wouldn't work in all browsers, e.g., not in older IE which doesn't support `preventDefault()`.)

Comment: You're right, there are two choices, either handling the even or returning false, depending on the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="expand();">Expand</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, insted of href="#" replace this href="javascript:;"