# Used to work but recently broken in Chrome

Tags: javascript

This used to work perfectly on my site but has recently stopped working on Chrome:

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('cite1').style.display='block';">
Cite
</a>
<div style="display:none; font-size:10pt; margin-top:11px; margin-bottom:7px;" id="cite1">
Information goes here
</div>
```

It used to correctly make the text appear, but now it changes the entire page to a white screen with the word "block" on it.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Just to be clear, can you include which version of Chrome and on which OS

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle with demonstration ? how are other browses working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make this look like, notice `return false;` at the end.

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('cite1').style.display='block';return false;">Cite</a>
```

Or, add `void(0);` at the end, like this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mMJ6Y/1/).

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/mMJ6Y/)

Comment: You shouldn't put JS in a href anyway. Onclick event handlers were meant to handle this.

Comment: This works, thanks. Regarding putting js in href, yes it is oldschool but I've done this for a reason as I don't want to influence the hashtag part of the URL on the page.

Comment: It's possible using old school `javascript:` way.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why it worked and stopped, but this works:
http://jsfiddle.net/6QZGp/

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('cite1').style.display='block';">
Cite
</a>
```

Comment: `href="#"` is inherently bad in that `#` links to the top of the page. You should still prevent the default browser action by returning `false` inside `onclick` in that case. Or you can use something else than an anchor element (e.g. a styled `span`) which is probably more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why is because the browser is trying to follow the link of the anchor (pointing to anything).

Try:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('cite1').style.display='block';return false;">
Cite
</a>
```

Good explaination of using of `href` and `onclick`: [JavaScript function in href vs. onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-function-in-href-vs-onclick)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/XQ7RP/