# Javascript in-line hiding within href attribute

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out a way to hide and reappear things on my pages:

```
<a href="javascript: document.getElementById('something').style.display = 'inline'">
prompt
</a>
<div id="something" style="display:none">
text
</div>
```

Why isn't this working? This is an approach that should let me reappear the text when I click the prompt.

I am specifically interested in why isn't my href=javascript part working, not workarounds using onclick.

Comment: Put your inline javascript in the `onclick` attribute of the `a` tag.

Comment: @mafafu Thanks, this works, but I am still interested in why the original doesn't work, since I don't see the fault within the malfunctioning code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript hide/show element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element)

Comment: @Allende I don't think so, they are already using the onclick part, I am specifically interested in why it doesn't work with my href="javascript:" code.

Comment: Ohh sorry you may want to edit your question and specify that, I actually don't know if you can "capture" the click within the href attribute, I will understand that your code will be executed (if it does) when the dom element is loaded only.

Comment: @Allende Thanks, done. Well, things like <a href="javascript: alert('text')">Script</a> obviously work, so this should too.

Comment: Omm wait I think I got your point, you're trying to execute the js as if you were running the script in the address bar, aren't you?

Comment: @Allende Possibly? I must admit, I do not know, I code using the trial and error method.

Comment: Jajaja I do the same, it's weird I just have IE9 here (work) doesn't work at all, all the document disappear and just the hiddent div appears. But someway I think this the right way, possible maybe but I wouldn't recommend use this way, still interesting thing

Comment: There are some interesting answers here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-function-in-href-vs-onclick re;ated to this way of use js

Comment: I think the browser is getting confused with all that script in the href tag. Not sure though. It DOES work in the href tag if you define your code as a function in a script tag and then call it from the href. However, I really would strongly advise against doing this all inline.

Comment: It seems to be a bad practice from the links Allende provided, but I don't still get why it doesn't work when it should.

Comment: @Kravaros Just try executing an anom function, seems to work (see my updated answer)

Comment: @Allende It does work, thank you for the effort!

Comment: @Kravaros, np I'm also learning js and well this was fun (in a mystical and obscure way but fun)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This (apperantly) will do the magic:

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('something').style.display = 'inline';})()">
```

But I won't bet for it, and also I'm not able to figure out why using self-executing anom function it works.

More about self-executing anom functions here:

http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/

Even more about this (ancient?) technique also known for the purists as **"Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)":**

http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

I'm still trying to understand why does it work, I think it's related to this functions are executed **"inmediatly"** and that it means before even the click event being propagated or the browser tries to navigate,it could be when the browser/jsengine access the href attr.

You should try then use the "onclick" event:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('something').style.display = 'inline'">
prompt
</a>
```

See this question (related to the above technique):

[javascript hide/show element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6242976/462889)

And related to use href attribute for js scripting see this question:

[JavaScript function in href vs. onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1070760/462889)