# Javascript: style.display:'block' doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css

any idea why this JavaScript just shows "block" and not the content of the (hidden) DIV?

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="mydiv" style="display:none">TEST</div>

<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display='block';">Show my DIV</a>

</body>
</html>
```

I also tried 'inline' but with the same result.

return false/true also failed.

onclick='' also failed.

I know there is style.visibility etc. but i need none/block.

Also the function should work inside the link, i don't want to call an external JS-function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Because you want to use an onclick event handler, not the href attribute:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display='block';">Show my DIV</a>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/x8HrY/)**

(side note: inline JavaScript is usually frowned upon)

Comment: :-D a clever way of using javascript

Comment: Doesn't explain what's happening in his original code though.

Comment: @MadSkunk - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-function-in-href-vs-onclick

Comment: In other words, "I don't know why it shows 'block' instead of acting as expected, here's a link re-enforcing the premise."

Answer (score 4):

The value of the javascript expression

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display='block'
```

is the string `'block'` - think of the way you can do `a=b='something'` - in javascript the value of an assignment expression is the assigned value.

If you try

```
<a href="javascript:'howdy'">link</a>
```

You'll find clicking the link navigates to a document containing just the word `howdy` - and the same thing is happening with your code. You can stop this happening by adding an explicit `void(0)`, or by wrapping the code in an immediately-invoked function expression that doesn't return a value (i.e. implicitly returns `undefined`), so:

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display='block';})()">
```

(This structure is commonly used in bookmarklets). However, as several comments have already pointed out, in general the use of `javascript:` hrefs is frowned upon, and you should consider using event handling instead.

Answer (score 0):

This code describes your problem: http://jsbin.com/jigiy/1

```
<div id="mydiv" style="display:none">TEST</div>
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display='block',false;">Show my DIV</a>
```

Why is this happening:

Javascript setters return the value input, so `document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display='block'` will return `'block'`, which is equal to `href="javascript:'block'"`. Now it refers to `about:blank` and sets its content to `block`.

I'm not sure why the browsers refer and set the content of `about:blank`, but i think this has something to do with data-urls.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id="mydiv" style="display:none">TEST</div>

<span onclick="document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display = 'block'">Show my DIV</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I just add snippet and fix typo error for your answer to make it easier to understand/use. Just, check date and other answer before posting, this question exist since 2014 and other answer seems as your own ;)

Answer (score 0):

-> my problem was using this method to display html tag:

```
const helloDiv = document.getElementById('hello')
helloDiv.style.display = "block"
```

-> the solution was to replace html tag:

```
document.getElementById('hello').style.display = "block"
```

and it worked for me