# Inline JavaScript in `href` not working as expected in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

Why doesn't this inline javascript work in Firefox? And how can I get it to work correctly in Firefox?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        h2 {display:inline; padding:0px 7px 0px;}
        h2 a {text-decoration:none}
        h2 a:link {color:#FFFFFF;} 
        h2#s0 {background-color:black;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="s0"><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('d0').style.display='block';">
Click me!</a></h2> 
    <div id="d0"
style="width:98%;border: 5px solid #000000;padding:3px; display:none;">
When you click the heading, this text should appear with a black
outline, with no gap between that and the heading background.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In Safari this appears as it should.
In Firefox it momentarily appears with a gap (as if the browser's in
quirks mode) then everything on the page vanishes, replaced by the word "block". At first I thought that meant Firefox was blocking it, but it says "inline" instead if that's what I set the style to display.

**EDIT:** The Javascript part of my problem is now solved. But there's still a difference in the way the heading background appears: it extends down to the div border in Safari, but not in Firefox. Is there a way to make it do so in Firefox?

Comment: Ha ha ha - this question title is classic!!

Comment: This works for me in Firefox 42 on Windows. What version are you using? Also, are there any extensions running?

Comment: Oh, you have to click the button first. You left that instruction out of your post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: style.display:'block' doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23859408/javascript-style-displayblock-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 11):

The closest working form of what you have is:

```
<a href="javascript:void(document.getElementById('d0').style.display='block');">
```

[Because](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void):

> When a browser follows a `javascript:` URI, it evaluates the code in the
>   URI and then *replaces the contents of the page with the returned
>   value*, unless the returned value is `undefined`. The `void` operator can
>   be used to return `undefined`.

`onclick` is the better option here.

Comment: Thanks Alex and @Burki. That has solved the Javascript problem.

Answer (score 3):

On OSX firefox version 41.0.1 I also experienced the same issue in fiddle. I do not know why it does not work, it could be a bug in FireFox but you can do this to have a somewhat similar working solution:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('d0').style.display='block';">
```

Comment: Add a « # » to href force some browser to scroll top of the current page (IE for example) so it's not a good practice.

Answer (score 3):

Replace your link with this:

```
<a href="javaScript: void(0);" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('d0').style.display='block';">
```

As far as i understand it, Firefox tries to open a URL if you put the javaScript call into the `href` attribute. (as you can see in your location bar)
Putting it in the `onclick` instead makes it work fine.

I guess you could also use some `preventDefault` or such, and you could also try `a href="#"`, but the `a href="javaScript: void(0);"` works just fine and is robust through all browsers i have tested so far.

Comment: Probably just a typo but i believe onclick is case sensitive.

Comment: thank you, @AtheistP3ace, i changed that, and officially it's all lower case as you said, although camelcase works on my system.

Comment: Yea I think some browsers are more forgiving than others. =]

Comment: @AtheistP3ace HTML tag names and attribute names are not case sensitive.

Comment: Well color me surprised. Always thought they were. Is this new to HTML5 or always like this? http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/documents.html#case-insensitivity

Comment: It is not new actually. HTML4 was same way. Sheesh. Shows what i know =[

Comment: XHTML is the case sensitive one