# window.close call is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, javascriptmvc

The `window.close()` method is not working in Chrome.

A "close" button exists in my Layout page with the JavaScript close method:

```
:javascript:window.open('', '_self','' );window.close();

<a  id="Close" href="javascript:window.open('', '_self','' );window.close();">Close</a>
```

When tried to call a controller method which returns the VIEW, on click of close button (which is in layout.cshtml) does not work. It throws an error:

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

This works correctly in cases like returning a partial view.  IE has no issues.

Comment: Please provide short example code showing the problem.

Comment: don't use javascript: label in href, instead use onclick handler (and don't use the javascript: label).  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11348403/61164

Comment: tried removing href, added event handler , but no luck.   <script type="text/javascript">$('#Close').click(function () {  window.close(); return false; });   <a id="Close" href="#">Close</a>

Comment: tried removing href, added event handler , but no luck.  (Layout.cshtml)  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")  <script type="text/javascript"> $('#Close').click(function () {  window.close(); return false; });</script> </head>
            <body>   <a id="Close" href="#">Close</a>