# Trigger Google Maps event listener on link clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I've a set of points which load on Google Maps and clicking the marker shows the infoWindow. Next, I wanted to show links specific to each point such that when the link is clicked, that specific point's infoWindow is show.

Here's my code:

```
var points = //array of points;
for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    t=new google.maps.Marker({position:latlng});
    google.maps.event.addListener(point[i], 'click', function(event) {
         //infobox.open(map, this);
    }
    show_e.push('<a href="#" id="'+point[i].id+'">'+point[i].name+'</a><br/>');

    //How to attach marker click event to the above link? 



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're looking for but I think this can help you:

[JavaScript function in href vs. onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-function-in-href-vs-onclick)