# Get event in onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, onclick

When I add an `onclick` handler to a page element by adding an event listener to it, I have access to the `event` javascript variable in the handler. E.g. `$('a')[0].addEventListener('click', doFoo);`

Is there a way to get that `event` when using the html attribute instead of adding an event listener? E.g. `<a href="..." onclick="doFoo(event);">bar</a>`?

Comment: @MikeRobinson does that mean that `<a href="..." onclick="doFoo(event);">bar</a>` would work as it's currently written?

Comment: yes but you shouldn't be putting js in your elements

Comment: @MartinCarney yes it should as stated in the question above

Comment: @bhspencer reference?

Comment: It should work by the way you used

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-function-in-href-vs-onclick