# Call JS function for specific id in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have below function in JS file name as **hello.js** inside **js** folder.

**JS**

```
function hello(){
    alert('hello world !);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/hello.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#hello").hello();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" id="hello">Click Me!</button> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

How do I attach the `hello()` function to the button with the `id="hello"`? I'm doing something wrong but I can't find what.

**Edit :** I recommend reading all answers for completeness.

**Edit2:** The purpose of this question was to clarify the general method of attaching functions to specific elements on html. The button and the click interaction was an example.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: You are currently trying to call hello as a jQuery extension method. You could write it as a jQuery hello plugin, but just using `click` will do :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to handle events with HTML or DOM.

**Defining it in HTML**

```
<button type="button" id="hello" onclick="hello();">Click Me!</button>
```

**Using JQuery**

```
$("#hello").click(hello);
```

**Attaching a function to the event handler using Javascript:**

```
var el = document.getElementById("hello");
    if (el.addEventListener)
        el.addEventListener("click", hello, false);
    else if (el.attachEvent)
        el.attachEvent('onclick', hello);

function hello(){
            alert("inside hello function");
}
```

Useful links

[MDN - onclick event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

[SO - Ans 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12627478/2524202)

[SO - Ans 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11348403/2524202)

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking to bind `click` event on button with id `hello` using `hello` as handler

```
$("#hello").click(hello);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind event handler.

```
$("#hello").on('click', hello);
```

Comment: Why `on` for a simple `click` handler case? Just makes the code longer and no extra gain here.

Comment: You very well know `click` is just shorthand for `.on( "click", handler )`. So why not tell OP the use of `.on()`

Comment: because, as I said, *it is longer* (6 characters longer to be precise)... One of the aims for JS code is conciseness :P

Answer (score 1):

Pure javascript:

```
var elm=document.getElementById("hello");
elm.onclick= function{ hello();};
```

Jquery:

```
$("#hello").click(hello() );
```

Comment: well, `on` is not a native javascript function, and in both examples, function `hello` is called , not passed as parameter.

Comment: Not sure why this answer has *any* upvotes as *it will not work as written*. Please correct your example :)