# How to call a javascript function from .js file on page load?

Tags: javascript, html

I really can't figure out how to do it. I need to call `somefunc()` from `file.js` file on page load.

My `file.js` contains:

```
function somefunc() {
    pc.somefunc(gotLocalDescription,

    function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }, {
        'mandatory': {
            'OfferToReceiveAudio': true,
            'OfferToReceiveVideo': true
        }
    });
}

// Socket.io    
var socket = io.connect('', {
    port: 1234
});

function sendCall(call) {
    socket.emit('call', call);
}

socket.on('call', function(call) {
    if (call.type === 'offer') {
        pc.setRemoteDescription(new SessionDescription(call));
        createAnswer();
    } else if (call.type === 'answer') {
        console.log('10--if call type is answer');
        pc.setRemoteDescription(new SessionDescription(call));
    } else if (call.type === 'candidate') {
        var candidate = new IceCandidate({
            sdpMLineIndex: call.label,
            candidate: call.candidate
        });
        pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
    }
});
```

Comment: function is a keyword / reserve word in javascript. You can't use it as function name, change it to something else and then try.

Comment: `function` name can never be `function`.

Comment: Post `file.js` content, I assume something is terribly wrong in it. The `javascript:function()` is wrong as well.

Comment: Why is the function call in the href attribute too? You'd normally see it as an `onclick` event.

Comment: Thanks, Parkash Kumar. I wrote it just for example. My function is actually in different name. Anyway I edited it for you.

Comment: @tagaism, Are your script and html files on same path?

Comment: @ParkashKumar yes, both are in same folder.

Comment: Are you observing any issues in console?

Comment: On both console (server and client) everything is clear.

Comment: Actually I want my function to run, when page is loaded.

Comment: Then you can wrap your function call in DOM ready load event, either using javascript or jQuery.

Comment: First, debug (by adding alert / console log) your method to make sure that it is being called from external file.

Comment: Yes, I did it. It is being called from external file just fine.

Comment: So, finally you would like to call your method in file on page load, right?

Answer (score 0):

consider using

```
<a href="#" onClick="function_name()">Trigger</a>
```

instead

Comment: There won't be any issue on calling js function using achor href attribute, if you calling it using javascript:somefunc().

Comment: There may not be any issue but this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-function-in-href-vs-onclick have a better answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simple call the function which is in another file.
Have created a plunker.Also note it has a seperate file **file.js**. If you using name spacing please take care of that.

```
<a href="javascript:_testMe()">Click Me</a>
```

[WORKING COPY](http://plnkr.co/edit/dA4y5cSzLoP9BDlvBQMn?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks  @user2181397, actually I want my function to run, when page is loaded.

Comment: Not sure about exact requirement,you attached the function with href attribute & now want it to run on page load !?. If are looking to run it on page load use window.load or if you have jquery use $(document).ready(function(){..}

Comment: I did like you've offered, and it caused an error in js console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createOffer' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Using `window.onload` (pure javascript), you can call your `somefunc()` of `file.js` on page load, as following:

```
function somefunc() {
  alert('somefunc() of file.js called!');

  /*
  * Your logic goes here.
  */
}

window.onload = somefunc();
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/NVV7APnrci813pulnE7p?p=preview)

While, if you want to use `jQuery`, then include jquery source first and then your custom script file containing your method and DOM `ready` call, as following:

```
function somefunc() {
  alert('somefunc() of file.js called!');

  /*
  * Your logic goes here.
  */
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    somefunc();
});

// OR 

jQuery(function({
    somefunc();
});
```

First make sure you have included your `file.js` to head of your html and the location to file is correct.

Comment: @tagaism, Now that's something I think, you would like to have. Isn't it?

Comment: thanks for your help. But I guess i didn't convey the question's meaning. Anyway i'll search for solution and let you know, if i find it.

Comment: Ohhh gosh, you are still having problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:function_name()"> click </a>
```

But first you must include **file.js** in you html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js">
```