# A Href= "javascript :;"

Tags: javascript, href

a href= "javascript :;" class="filter" data-filter="" works fine, but it does not work with responsive meanmenu by meanthemes, can someone please help, thanks in advance.

I tried the option in meanmenu not to remove the class attributes but it failed.

Comment: Don't understand what you are asking for. Please edit your question

Comment: I am creating a webpage with a hyperlinks menu bar on the top of the page. When I click a link in the menu bar I am calling a javascript that will display portfolio item images in the body of the page. Means when I click web design it shows images tagged under web design. When I click mobile it displays images pertaining to mobile. I already have it working from a template that I downloaded. But when I am using the mobile responsive menu bar called meanmenu the javascript does not work. The mobile responsive menu only opens links to Web pages. I hope you are perceiving my problem now...thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Sorry, but I can't find the begining of something that would start to make any sense in your question.
- It seems to be very specific to a particular context. You could perhaps succintly describe that context ...
- ... and specifically what you are trying to achieve.

Some hints, though :

```
<a href="javascript:§some code here§;" §other relevant attributes§>;" ...>
```

is generally not a good idea :

> [The HTML Anchor Element () defines a hyperlink to a location on the same page or any other page on the Web.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

*The* element that is intended to react to a click by executing JS code is the

```
<button>
```

Second best would be a

```
<div>
```

or at last resort a

```
<span>
```

if you really need your action to be in-line, which would be a bit unorthodox from a UX point of view.

At any rate : give your clickable element an `id` attribute, then, *in a distinct and separate* `.js` file, define what it does like so :

```
document.getElementById('thatId').addEventListener('click', function(e){
     /* 
     * Your code goes here.
     * The event argument e holds all what you need to know about
     * what was clicked.
     */
});
```

In the "Related" side bar, I see [this very relevant thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11348403/3617432). Read it seriously.

Comment: I am creating a webpage with a hyperlinks menu bar on the top of the page. When I click a link in the menu bar I am calling a javascript that will display portfolio item images in the body of the page. Means when I click web design it shows images tagged under web design. When I click mobile it displays images pertaining to mobile. I already have it working from a template that I downloaded. But when I am using the mobile responsive menu bar called meanmenu the javascript does not work. The mobile responsive menu only opens links to Web pages. I hope you are perceiving my problem now...thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am creating a webpage with a hyperlinks menu bar on the top of the page. When I click a link in the menu bar I am calling a javascript that will display portfolio item images in the body of the page. Means when I click web design it shows images tagged under web design. When I click mobile it displays images pertaining to mobile. I already have it working from a template that I downloaded. But when I am using the mobile responsive menu bar called meanmenu the javascript does not work. The mobile responsive menu only opens links to Web pages. I hope you are perceiving my problem now...thanks