# Output variable inside an href - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, magnific-popup

I am using Magnific Popup for my gallery. When you click on a thumbnail, it popups the image. I am trying to add a "Download image" button inside the popup. I have the HTML snippet displaying fine, but the href of the download link needs to be populated with the img url.

Here is the JS code:

```
markup: '<div class="mfp-figure">'+
                '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
                '<div class="download-img"><a href="#">Download image</a></div>'+
                '<figure>'+
                    '<div class="mfp-img"></div>'+
                    '<figcaption>'+
                        '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar">'+
                            '<div class="mfp-title"></div>'+
                            '<div class="mfp-counter"></div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</figcaption>'+
                '</figure>'+
            '</div>',
```

How do I put the image src variable in the anchor's href?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the Magnific Popup API you will see that it provides a callback for the event `markupParse`

So add this to your Magnific Popup options

```
callbacks: {
      markupParse: function(template, values, item) {
       template.find('.download-img a').prop('href',item.src);
      }
    }
```

Full demo at http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/reoqQv

Comment: *edit. Where exactly do I place it in the options section?

Comment: I found out where to put the callback code, but its still not changing the a href to the img url

Comment: @Garrettj944 is your page live somewhere ?

Comment: Yes, it is here: savvysumo.com/photobank/

Comment: Did you find the issue?

Comment: @Garrettj944 you should not be changing the ***jquery.magnific-popup.min.js*** file (*that is the plugin code, leave it intact*). You should alter the ***jquery.mediaBoxes.js*** file. (*and that is where you should put all you magnific popup options, like the markup and the callbacks. You should un-minify the file first for identifying where to make the changes more easily.*)

Answer (score 1):

Just put the variable out of quotes.

```
markup: '<div class="mfp-figure">'+
                '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
                '<div class="download-img"><a href="' + yourVar + '">Download image</a></div>'+
                '<figure>'+
                    '<div class="mfp-img"></div>'+
                    '<figcaption>'+
                        '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar">'+
                            '<div class="mfp-title"></div>'+
                            '<div class="mfp-counter"></div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</figcaption>'+
                '</figure>'+
            '</div>',
```

Comment: Doesn't work. If you want to look at the code I can pay you

Comment: I don't need money. I do it for passion. Could you show me the entire code or at least the piece where the variable is and the whole magnific popup invocation.

Comment: Alright, here is the js file for the popup: http://pastebin.com/QcpRnjQS CTRL+F "download" to find where my html snippet is.

Comment: Is it the updated code? BTW, where should your variable come from? Where is it defined?

Answer (score 0):

The following link shows you a number of ways you can use href some are good and others are bad. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11348403/886393

specifically the answer by username demp.

Thanks,
Paras

Comment: I am trying to echo a js variable, not run a function when they click. If you are willing to look into the code, I can pay you

Comment: post the code here. I can help you out and so can the community. I do this for practice. I do not want to get paid.

Comment: @Jakub is looking into it, you can too if you'd like. See my comment his answer :)