# How to use functions on href (html/js)

Tags: javascript, html, function, hyperlink, href

want to build a function inside a href link.
should look like this

```
<a href="javacript:destroy();"></a>
```

How do i complete it correct?

Comment: You can bind the function inside onClick event . Like -  <a href="#" onClick="destroy();"></a>

Comment: why do you want to have function instead href link??. Try to with div or button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onclick` to trigger a function instead of `href`

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" onclick="destroy()"></a>
```

**JS**

```
function destroy()
{   //rest of the code
    return false;  // return false is use to prevent default behavior 
}
```

Note: If you dont use `return false` or `event.preventDefault` it will execute the default behavior

Answer (score 0):

There are different option for you to use.
Most of them already answered [in another question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11348403/6803886)

Sum it up:

You can do it like this (the correct way):

```
<a id="myLink" title="Click to do something" href="PleaseEnableJavascript.html" onclick="destroy();return false;">link text</a>
```

What it means is that after the destroy function is called it wont direct the user to the link provided. Alternatively you can use jQuery to make a listener on the specific a href like this:

```
$('#myLink').click(function(){
    MyFunction(); 
    return false; 
});
```

The rest can be read on the provided link :)