# JS Toggle doesnt works

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I need some help with my website.
I want to integrate the jquery toggle function. But it doesn't work.
I don't have a lot experience with jQuery.

Here is my code:

```
<a href="javascript:toggle('exp');">Klick</a>

<div id="exp" style="display:none;"> hallo </div>

<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<script>
function toggle(str)
{
    $(str).slideToggle('slow');
}   
</script>
```

Has anyone an idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: Here is a good learning resource for selectors:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

Comment: You should using a proper event-handler instead of having a js-function in the `href`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11348403/4202224) for a discussion about this topic

Comment: i know this option and i already use it. But i didnt know why its better. Thank u it is very interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing `#` before [id selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) in your code.

```
function toggle(str){
    $('#' + str).slideToggle('slow');
    //-^----
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what to toggle.

```
$("#exp").slideToggle('slow');
```

See Jquery doc: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/