# How can i send dynamic values using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dynamic

Here my dynamic script:

```
<a href="inv-controller.php?res=yes&id_job=<?=$myjobs['id_job'];?>" class="btn btn-primary">Accept And Send Invite To All Students</a>
<a href="inv-controller.php?res=no&id_job=<?=$myjobs['id_job'];?>" class="btn btn-default">Reject And Delete</a>
```

From the above two links there are two dynamic parameters which i want to send using ajax call how can i do that..?

There are two buttons there Accept and reject.
i can do this with core php and i want to do this without refreshing the page.

Here what i have tried.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function jobResponse(jobId){
        var jobid = $(jobId).attr('id');  // im confusing in this line
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: 'inv-controller.php',
            data: {action: "jobreplay", value: jobid},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                //blah blah blah
            }   
        });
    }
</script>
```

how can i rewrite the two `<a>` tags according to ajax.

Comment: you can use javascript in href, just like `<a href="javascript:jobRespond(<?=$myjobs['id_job'];?>);" class="btn btn-default">Reject And Delete</a>)"`

Comment: will that work with out refreshing the page and how can i get the respone whether it is success or not

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano you can, but please don't. It's not the 90s any more. Use unobtrusive event handlers

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i'm going OT, but read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-function-in-href-vs-onclick)

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano That just backs up my original point - JS in `href` or `on*` attributes is outdated and you should use unobtrusive handlers instead - regardless of if you use jQuery or any other library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="jobResponse("yes",<?php echo $myjobs['id_job'];?>)">Accept And Send Invite To All Students</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default" onclick="jobResponse("no",<?php echo $myjobs['id_job'];?>)">Reject And Delete</a>
```

and get in function like this

```
function jobResponse(type,jobId){

var frm_data = { type : type,
                 jobId : jobId
                }
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'inv-controller.php',
        data: frm_data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            //blah blah blah
        }   
    });
}
```

you can get in your ajax php file. frm data as post .

Answer (score 2):

It'll be better to use `data-*` attributes like :

```
<a href="inv-controller.php" data-res="yes" data-job-id="<?=$myjobs['id_job'];?>" class="btn btn-primary inv-controller">Accept And Send Invite To All Students</a>
<a href="inv-controller.php" data-res="no" data-job-id="<?=$myjobs['id_job'];?>" class="btn btn-default inv-controller">Reject And Delete</a>
```

Then attach click event to the links `a` with class `inv-controller` :

```
$('a.inv-controller').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var res = $(this).data('res');
  var job_id = $(this).data('job-id');
  var url = $(this).attr('href');

  $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: {action: "jobreplay", value: job_id},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
          //blah blah blah
      }   
  });
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `Delegated-events` ? Why ?

Comment: Right, updated my answer, thanls for your intervention.

Answer (score 1):

You Can do like this , Look at the parameter jobId passed to it in value: jobId

```
     <a href="javascript:jobResponse(<?=$myjobs['id_job'];?>)" class="btn btn-primary">Accept And Send Invite To All Students</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
function jobResponse(jobId) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'inv-controller.php',
        data: { action: "jobreplay", value: jobId },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            //blah blah blah
        }
    });
}
```