# How to pass a variable from a href to javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my `a href` and I want to pass this value on a JavaScript. How do I alert it?

```
<a href="javascript:void();" class="right-bar-toggle" data="<?php echo "1"; ?>" >
  <i class="zmdi zmdi-notifications-none"></i>
</a>
```

My javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var a = $(this).attr("data");
  alert(a);
});
```

Comment: `javascript:void();` is a totally useless combination of no-ops and syntax errors. And you [shouldn't use `javascript:` urls at all](http://stackoverflow.com/a/134957/1048572) (and [not even `onclick` attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1070760/1048572))

Answer (score 0):

You need to name the data attr.

```
<a href="javascript:void();" class="right-bar-toggle" data-test="<?php echo "1"; ?>" >
```

and

```
$("a").data("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on your html, your script must be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var a = $("a").attr("data");
  alert(a);
});
```