# Should I use window.open or a href with onclick

Tags: javascript, next.js, onclick, window

So I'm making a Next.js app where users can download software. Each software has a download link. If a user clicks download I want to do 2 things:

1. Open the download URL in a new tab
2. Make a API request to my backend to let it know that a user clicked download

So now im left with 2 choices:

a) Use a button with onclick of window.open("downloadUrl", "_blank", "noreferrer,noopener")

b) Use Download

I also would like to have the most across browser accessability.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you mean by option b) 'Use Download' ?

Answer (score 1):

For maximum accessibility, I recommend you instead use an anchor tag with an `onClick` method (this strategy is mentioned in [this losely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-href-vs-onclick-for-callback-function-on-hyperlink)).

If you're using JSX:

```
<a title="Some title for accessibility" href="http://downloadlink.com" onClick={()=>sendPingToServer()}>Some Text</a>
```