# How transmit parameters from href by not method GET?

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

How transmit parameters from href by not method GET?
I use spring. maybe spring tools can to help me?
by method get:

```
<a href="saveCandidate?id=${candidate.id}">${candidate.name}</a>
```

candidate.id transmit by get method

How transmit candidate.id by Post(for example method)?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "not method GET". Could you show an example?

Comment: POST DELETE PUT and other methods

Comment: that's the answer... use POST DELETE or PUT... i'd recommend post

Comment: I edit question. It is understand now?

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: I don't like javaScript

Comment: It is jsp expression language

Comment: Yes it is Expression language,which replaced scriplets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,By default href hits get method,There is no way to specify a method.

Try some html `form`  to specify Method's or move your  logic to `GET`.

If you can use client script (`javascript`),There is possibility do it with.

Comment: maybe you can show how make it using javascript?

Comment: See here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275039/how-to-make-a-submit-out-of-a-a-href-a-link