# How to make the submit button a href and image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make my submit button a image and also when clicked it links to another page.

This is the current submit button which works but isn't a href or image

```
<input type="submit" name="submit"  alt="add" onclick="add()" >
```

These are the multiple methods I've tried but none of them seem to work. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

1. `<input type="image" name="submit" src="img/add.png" class="addButton" id="addButton" />`

2.

```
<a href="bookmarks.php" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()"><img src="img/add.png" class="addButton" id="addButton" alt="add button" /> </a>
```

3.

```
<a href="bookmarks.php" onclick="document.forms['form'].submit(); return false;" type="submit" name="submit"><img src="img/addToBookmarks.png" class="addButton" id="addButton" alt="add button" /></a>
```

Lastly the form itself on stadiumLargeSymbol.php:

```
      <form class="form" action="stadiumLargeSymbol.php?submit=true" method="post">
<img id="enlargedSymbol" type="text" size="60" name="pathOfSymbol" src='' />
              <br />
              <input class="inputBox" type="hidden" name="pathOfSymbol" id="pathOfSymbol" />
              <script>
              var querySrc = URI(window.location.href).search(true).src;
              $("#enlargedSymbol").prop("src", querySrc);
              $('#pathOfSymbol').val(querySrc);
              </script>

 <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br/>
       <input type="submit" name="submit"  alt="add to bookmarks button" onclick="add()" >

              </form>
```

Comment: use <a> tag with background image

Comment: <img src="(your image url)" onclick="add()" />

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a submit out of a <a href...>...</a> link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275039/how-to-make-a-submit-out-of-a-a-href-a-link)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/0e2rykap/

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>
      <button type="submit" class="btn_submit">
        <img src="http://www.smartwebby.com/imgs/tutorials/fireworks/website-design/submit-button.jpg" />
      </button>
    </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

you can use javascript to mimick the href redirection

Answer (score 3):

Try giving id to div where your image is being rendered, Assuming id of your div is "divImage",You can write following is JS :

```
$("#divImage").click(function(){
  //On Click Event
});
```

You can write your form submission code and redirecting code inside "on-click" event.Your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

Apply a background image to the submit button using css.

```
// html
<input type="submit" name="submit"  alt="add" onclick="add()" >

// css
form input[type=submit]{
  background-image: url('img/example.png');
}
```

And add other styling properties as necessary. Don't forget to remove the border and such from the button in the css.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `input` type `submit`

Use a `div` , inside `div` set a image `tag` like below

```
<div id="yoyo">
   <img src="whateva" />
</div>
```

Now on click of `img` tag `ID` or `Div` `ID` , `submit` the `form`.

Like :

```
    $( "#yoyo" ).click(function() {
      $( "#FormID" ).submit();

      //or if you want to redirect than
       window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    });
```